# In Azure AD, is it possible to change the owner of a Windows 10 device?

Tags: windows-10, entra-id

In Azure AD, is it possible to change the owner of a device, if so, how?

Comment: Since this question was posed, Microsoft has added the ability to change the "owner" of a device. As mentioned below, it is best to Wipe a device, when assigning it to a new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for Intune managed devices, for reasons of security and digital hygiene, the best practice is to reset the device, then have the new user go through the AutoPilot process.

For those who may not agree with this practice, there is now an option to change or remove the primary user on the Property view for the device.

Answer (score 8):

You can change the owner of the device via PowerShell.

Add the new owner.

```
Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId <Device ObjectId> -RefObjectId <New Owner ObjectID>
```

Then remove the previous owner.

```
Remove-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId <Device ObjectId> -OwnerId <Previous Owner ObjectID>
```

You can find the device's "ObjectId" using the following command.

```
Get-AzureADDevice
```

You can find the owners "ObjectId" in Azure Portal or via.

```
Get-AzureAdUser
```

You can use the Cloud Shell feature in the Portal to execute the commands or you could install them locally and connect up.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new owner and then remove the previous owner. For the details, you could refer to this  [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#devices).

Comment: Are you referring to the documentation for the commands Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner and Remove-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner?

Comment: Have you tried these commands?

Comment: No. We are prototyping in production and didn't have time this round to wait for an answer. Instead, we went through the convoluted process of removing the device from Azure AD and re-AutoPilot-ing it.